# How do I handle data I receive from an outside API within VueJS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm returning an object from an API(Amazon MWS) call. I am able to pass this data to a vue instance within the same php file as a prop and display the results. Although this is just for test purposes and isn't very flexible.

What is the best way to handle a situation like this? Should I store the data from this object to a database, make a call from the vue instance to the database? If so how do I go about this? If not what are the best alternatives to handle passing data from an API call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an API that sits in front of their API. Return what you want from your API after making a call to their API.

```
public function getProduct($pid)
{
    $product = $this->mwsservice->getProduct($pid);

    return response()->json($product);
}
```

Then call this function from vue when you want the data, make sure you have a Laravel route setup for it.

Comment: Here to save the day again. So create a controller to pull in the data, then another method to pass the data to the vue instance through a http call like "Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');" ?

Comment: @Pyreal Yeah, that would be my recommendation to you.

Comment: You should also setup a function that would transform the data received from the external API so in the event it properties changes you can make the change in one place (e.g. your controller).